# Postman 2 OAuth tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, postman-collection-runner

Has anyone had to deal with 2 OAuth 2.0 tokens in postman? I am in the process of automating some API calls for testing and have been stuck at a point where I had to make 2 Authorization requests to get a successful response. I have one authorization token at the collection level and other at the request level. However every time I generate a token at the collection level and then when I generate the second token the first one is being overridden? Is there a workaround? I have tried collection variables and variables and all of them seem to be overridden on the second OAuth call.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the story is you cannot use 2 bearer tokens in a single request. It is not practically possible. Do you use 2 passwords to open your account? No, right. Same is the case with bearer token. Maybe if you tell what you need to achieve using both the tokens someone might be able to help.